# Isolating remainder in nasm program

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, nasm

I'm currently writing a NASM program on x86 Linux and I'm trying to perform a calculation that divides the first command line arg (a year) by the first leap year check. I want to check if the remainder is 0 or not but I'm struggling with how to do that. I know the div command stores the answer in a certain register and a remainder in another but right now I'm just using test. Here's the code

```
        global  main
        extern  puts
        extern  printf
        extern  atoi

        section  .text

main:
        sub     rsp, 8
        cmp     rdi, 2
        jne     error1              ; jump if aguments != 1
        mov     rdi, [rsi+8]
        call    atoi
        test    rdi, fourTest
        jnz     notLeapYear
        jmp     done
testTwo:
        jmp     done

notLeapYear:
        mov     edi, nLeap
        call    puts
        jmp     done
error1:
        mov     edi, badArgs
        call    puts
        jmp     done  

done:
        add     rsp, 8
        ret

badArgs:
        db      "Requires exactly one argument", 5, 0

nLeap:
        db      "Not a leap year", 5, 0

        section  .data
fourTest:      dq       4
hundTest:      dq       100
fHundTest:     dq       400
```

I believe I need to change the test rdi, fourTest to using div but don't know how to isolate the remainder and determine if I should jump to the next test or if I should jump to is not a leap year.

Comment: Not sure what you are struggling with, apparently you know how `div` works since you described it pretty well (if somewhat vaguely). Also note that to use `test` to get `modulo 4` you need to do `test rdi, 3` not `test rdi, 4` as you have done.

Comment: @Jester sorry I'm fairly new to Assembly and x86 architecture so I may not always describe things perfectly. I changed the line to test rdi, 3 my jump still does not jnz to my notLeapYear section that should print out "Not a leap year". For example I input 2005 into my command line which should not be 0 when modded with 4, however it ignored that jnz and jumps straight to done.

Comment: Also note that `atoi` returns the result in `eax` not `rdi`.

Comment: @Jester That was my issue! Thank you so much Jester

Comment: An instruction reference would do you a lot of good.

Comment: I get credit for `mov rdi, [rsi+8]`? ;-)

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes Michael! Thank you. Sorry for not replying to the other thread. Huge help.

Comment: LOL I was just poking fun, wasn't any big deal. I realized that this was a followup to your question yesterday where you clearly made a lot more progress. I preferred to guide you without giving you the entire answer.

Answer (score 0):

First, return values from functions go into `eax`, so that's where the `atoi` result will be.  Then use `div` like this:

```
xor edx,edx
div 4
```

Now the result of the division will be in `eax`, and the remainder will be in `edx`.

Comment: `test edi, 3` being zero would mean it is evenly divisible by 4 without the overhead of `div`.

Comment: @MichaelPetch Yes it would work for four but we also need to check if the year input is modulo by 100 and 400 = 0. Whereas test only works with powers of 2 (bitwise and). So for our next two we will try to use div and keep an eye on remainders. Thank you.

Comment: I didn't know NASM allowed dividing by an immediate as in `div 4`.