# Leap-year NASM Assembly program

Tags: assembly, nasm, elf

I am currently working on building an assembly program using NASM elf64 x64 which will tell whether an inputted year is a leap year or not. Currently, I have hard coded the year as 1986, but in final version it should take in a command line argument.

However. I keep getting a floating point error that I cannot figure out where it is coming from.

```
    global main
    extern puts
    section .text

main:
    mov rax, year
    cwd
    mov rcx, 400
    div rcx
    test rdx, rdx
    jz _is_leap

    mov rax, year
    cwd
    mov rcx, 100
    div rcx
    test rdx, rdx
    jz _no_leap

    mov rax, year
    test rax, 3
    jz _is_leap

 year
    dq      1986, 10, 0      


 _no_leap:
    db      "This is NOT a leap year", 10, 0            ;print out is not a leap year
    jmp _after

 _is_leap:
    db      "This is a leap year", 10, 0            ;print is a leap year
    jmp _after

 _after:
    ret
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Just out of curiosity what is the ", 10, 0" after the year for?

Comment: `cwd` doesn't do what you think it does. You should simply zero `rdx` instead. And as Matti said, don't jump into data :)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen Was under the impression those were necessary to complete a "db" statement

Comment: No, you do not need random magic numbers to "complete" a data statement. It's common to see them after strings because they represent a line feed and a null byte to terminate the string which is useful when passing them to functions that expect a null terminated string.

Comment: You might want to look at your [classmates code](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36901647/3857942) to get an idea about how to use `puts` to print strings.

Comment: Something else that may catch you a bit off guard is this `mov rax, year` which moves the **address** of the label `year` into _RAX_. I think you want to move the **value** at the memory address associated with the label `year`. I think you may have wanted indirection with something like `mov rax, [year]` .In your case that would move the quadword value 1986 into _RAX_

Answer (score 0):

A floating point error in a program that only deals in integers is usually caused by an incorrect division. In your case it doesn't look like a division by zero so it would be a division overflow as pointed out by Michael Petch in the comments.

A bigger problem is though that you are jumping to a location that does not contain valid code. For instance, your `_no_leap` location contains the bytes that represent the string "This is NOT a leap year\n\0" and you're telling the system to interpret that as code. That's just not going to work.

Simply executing data does not make the computer print it. You need to make a system call to print out a string. The way to do that is platform-dependent.

Comment: There are two general causes of an integer division error with the DIV instruction. Div by zero, and division overflow where the quotient can't be represented in the destination register. This is usually the case when people do DIV and don't zero out DX/EDX/RDX register. In this case `xor edx, edx` would be warranted for unsigned division.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know that overflow causes the same error. Then it would be the division that is the problem. After that's fixed it would immediately crash by trying to execute data.